# How to display only one representative contour line in legend?

Tags: qgis

I have a layer of topographic contour lines, graduated by color (using QGIS). My legend wants to display every level and its color. This is not feasible. I need to simply show one representative line, which I'll edit to be labeled "Topographic contour lines: 5-meter intervals". How can I include one representative line, but not all of the various levels?
Thanks
TVZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Legend editor, expand your Contours item.  Highlight all but one of the sub-items (i.e. contours) and click the green minus button at the bottom of the Legend items pane.  This will delete all but one of your contours, just in the same way as you can delete and entire legend item.

Just an idea, but instead of only having one contour, you could leave three contours to suggest the colour and height range (the lowest, the middle and the highest) and label the main item "Topographic contour lines: 5-meter intervals:" and just have the heights for the actual contours.  This would be a bit more informative as somebody reading your map will instantly know the height range which is visible.

Alternatively, add a duplicate layer for contours and given them all the same symbology.  With the layer visible, go into Map Composer and add it (green plus button at the bottom of the legend items).  Edit the text to suit.  Then go back to the Main QGIS window and deactivate the layer.  This will leave it in the Lengend but prevent it showing on the map.  You need to have it active initially otherwise you won't be able to add the item.